# StructureMap: Configure concrete classes at run time?

Tags: structuremap, ioc-container

I know that Concrete Types can be configured with Structure Map the following way:

```
ForRequestedType<Rule>().TheDefault.Is.Object(new ColorRule("Green"));
```

This works if you know the type ahead of time.  I want to do it at run time, and there does not seem to be a way.  Can some one enlighten me?  What I want to do is something like the following:  (This appears to be not supported by structure map)

```
ForRequestedType(typeof(Rule)).TheDefault.Is.Object(new ColorRule("Green"));
```

The reason for this is because I'm working on a wrapper for structure-map's configuration.  And I will not know the type ahead of time.  For the .Object(new ColorRule("Green")) I am going to be passing in a delegate instead, which would actually construct the object on request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently Jeremy added the ability to configure a Func as a builder for your type. Here is an example of using a delegate/lambda as your builder.

```
    public interface IRule
{
    string Color { get; set; }
}

public class ColorfulRule : IRule
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public ColorfulRule(string color)
    {
        Color = color;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class configuring_delegates
{
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        var color = "green";
        Func<IRule> builder = () => new ColorfulRule(color);

        var container = new Container(cfg=>
        {
            cfg.For<IRule>().Use(builder);
        });

        container.GetInstance<IRule>().Color.ShouldEqual("green");

        color = "blue";

        container.GetInstance<IRule>().Color.ShouldEqual("blue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but I can't use the Generics, since I am not going to know the type at build time, only at run time.   Also, for my problem I need it to work with interface-less objects.  however I did try your method like this:   cfg.For(typeof(IRule)).Use(builder)  but that causes structure map to throw an exception: StructureMap configuration failures:
Error:  104 ColorfulRule cannot be plugged into type IRule.

Comment: Never mind I think I was able to make it work with modification of your code.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad you got it working for your needs. Sorry you can't use interfaces they make working with containers much easier and give you better control over your abstractions.

Comment: How did you manage to solve this? I've just run in the same problem.